# Каким из способов сегодня получают данные из базы данных в С#?

Tags: c#, sql

Какой на сегодня способ наиболее актуальный получения данных из баз данных в С#?

Я еще новичок и относительно недавно (на данный момент полтора года работаю сразу после института) пришел в свою компанию и пишу desktop приложения wpf. Единственный программист который делает такие же приложения сказал что грузит данные из БД в клиент с помощью WCF. Я с ходу (как только пришел) не смог о его примерам понять как это создавать. Но по прошествии года до меня дошло (долго потому что потом были задачи не связанные с выгрузкой и не задавался таким вопросом) и смог реализовать.

До этого я просто получал данные с помощью стандартной схемы встроенной в VisualStudio (.xsd) именуемая DataSet.
Для меня такая схема показалось простой, но позже вылезли ее недостатки в виде ограниченного количества типов данных и их не nullable версии, вследствие чего приходилось всегда преобразовывать типы с object к нужному.

В WCF такого недостатка нет но как я прочитал это уже достаточно старый способ получать данные. Да и к тому же думаю избыточный, если приложение состоит всего и нескольких таблиц и форм для их изменения и еще создает сервис для получения данных.

Читал еще про EntityFramework. Но его тоже что-то не получается пока освоить. Так как он создает свой, непонятный для меня код, и там в половине случаев приходится вручную описывать название и тип поля (в случае Dynamic-SQL в процедурах).

Какой из этих способов актуален/удобен или есть еще способы?

Comment: лично я ушел от громоздокого, на мой взгляд, EntityFramework со множеством его нюансов, на linq2db. Счастлив уже несколько лет )

Comment: Зависит от размера самой БД. Можно пользоваться легковесным Dapper'ом.

Comment: @iluxa1810 у нас все построено на процедурах в СУБД и на клиента уходят фильтрованные данные самое большее миллион записей. Я ищу наиболее простой способ получать схему с процедур и не описывая вручную все поля.

Comment: *Какой из этих способов актуален/удобен* — EF/EFCore один из. Если надо в основном чтение, то вполне заходит ADO.NET (можно с Dapper или еще каким маппером поверх)

Comment: @Ackbar, а назад данные пользователь возвращает?

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, так же на процедурах изменение данных и внутри процедур транзакции

Comment: _грузит данные из БД в клиент с помощью WCF_ - это возможно лишь в том случае, если уже имеется сервер wcf. Но сам wcf-сервер тем или иным образом должен  получать данные из СУБД - то есть возвращаемся к вашему вопросу: как получить эти данные.

Comment: Если проблема в том, что бы описать модели, то ты можешь нарисовать себе шаблон T4, а внем ты можешь описать логику обхода таблиц БД и он тебе автоматически будет классы генерить

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov wcf-сервер создается локально и пишется рядом с основным приложением (да для каждого приложения получается свой мини сервер, поэтому мне и не хочется даже начинать их писать и конечно же я не говорю это своему начальнику который и пропагандирует wcf)

Comment: @iluxa1810 в этом и дело что у нас данные не с таблиц берутся ( как я понял это основной метод получения данных в мире - создавать запрос на клиенте и иметь все описание таблиц и их связи) а с процедур. Соответственно может ваш способ не подойдет. А если процедура может вернуть разные наборы полей то модель вообще не захочет создаваться (только что сейчас попробовал создать модель такой процедуры на ORMDataModel входящий в DevExpress который мы используем, и он даже не дал создать под него модель в мастере создания моделей).

Comment: Чтобы получить данные откуда-либо, нужно описание схемы. В вашем случае, должно быть описание всех ваших хранимых процедур. Если такого описания нет, то у вас имеются следующие выборы: уволиться; страдать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov конечно же у меня есть доступ к процедурам и я могу получить их описание. Но по краймер мере в стандартном xsd я мог указать процедуру в мастере и он сам мог получить поля если это не dynamic-sql.

Comment: _процедура может вернуть разные наборы полей_ - вот этот _разный набор полей_ должен быть где-то описан. Не в коде t-sql, а в документе для человека.

Comment: Кстати, какая СУБД используется?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov MS SQL. так он и описан. но некоторые инструменты не могут его прочитать (я не говорю про dynamic-sql там надо вручную да).

Comment: какое отношение WCF имеет к работе с БД? Работа с БД может быть два варианта, ADO.NET и ORM, ORM делится еще на группы а те в свою очередь имеют по несколько подходов

Comment: @pashagoroshko предположу, что речь идет об [ado.net data services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/wcf/)

Answer (score 1):

Надо разделять котлет от мух. **WCF**!=**EF**, например.
Само получение может идти разными способами, но почти все они обычно сводятся к **ADO.NET** (преусловутые *Command*, *DataSet* и т.д.), **EF** (*DataContext*, *POCO* и т.д.) а также какие-нибудь другие похожие прослойки. **EF** предполагает более ООП-подход, с **ADO.NET** приходится больше писать очевидных вещей, но при этом и гибкость вроде как выше.
**WCF**, **WebAPI** и всё остальное - это уже дополнительный слой, который можно положить (а можно и не ложить) между кодом, который будет работать с базой и кодом, который должен реализовывать конечную логику. Классика жанра - это приложение с **ASP.NET MVC** на одном сервере, службы **WCF/WebAPI** на другом и ещё отдельно база. Сложно, но гибко по части балансировки и повышения надёжности. Также рекомендую взглянуть на приложенную схему(она старовата, но всё ещё актуальна).

[image: схема]

Comment: Я понимаю что они не равны но это не мешает wcf быть таким же инструментом чтобы получить данные. Я его озвучил чтобы посмотреть использует ли кто его так же как у нас в виде локального сервера. Я лично по такому пути не пошел и сейчас получаю по ADO.NET.

Comment: Это всё равно, что считать комбайн и хлебовоз "такими же инструментами, чтобы получить хлеб". Логика, рекомендую вам подтянуть логику, можете взять учебник Кузьмина.

Comment: а вы не думали что может быть мне просто никто не рассказал ключевое - как должно быть? если по вашему использовать wcf чтобы в desktop приложении получить данные ненормально то это не обязательно я настолько неуч и не компетентен, я в посте рассказал что у нас так использует единственный человек который тоже пишет desktop приложение и у которого я так сказать учился.

Comment: >"если по вашему использовать wcf чтобы в desktop приложении получить данные ненормально" -     
Я этого не говорил.

> "мне просто никто не рассказал ключевое - как должно быть"    

- Картинка выше, на ней как раз про "как бывает с WCF".  

Расклад такой, что WCF как бы _староват_ с одной стороны, а с другой все эти промежуточные слои вам могут и не понадобиться. Когда несколько БД и несколько серверов, обслуживающих пользователей - промежуточные службы/сервисы актуальны. В противном случае как правило не нужно усложнять, если только это не задел на будущее.

Comment: да у нас несколько бд, картинка такая же и получается только вместо mvc - wpf

Comment: Так вот, если хотите на ходу менять БД (не просто "поменял строки подключения", а именно что разные базы могут быть), то сервисы (WCF, WebAPI или любые другие) могут быть оптимальным решением. И опять же рапределять нагрузку и делать шардирование проще.